# "a piece of debris" vs "a debris piece"

Tags: word-choice

In a scientific context, I need to write about the mitigation of space debris. For example, a wrecked old satellite can be known as debris. But the word `debris` is a mass noun, so I want to use a singular derivation of that. Which one of the following is a better option?

"a piece of debris" or "a debris piece"?

Comment: "The debris" is fine, but "a debris" is not.

Answer (score 1):

> "A piece of debris"

But there may be better ways to express what you want to say. You can say "A machine to remove debris" but not "a debris"